# Showing a pair is an excisive couple, Mayer-Vietoris sequence. singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X=X_1 \bigcup X_2$ and $A=X_1 \bigcap X_2$. Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are  closed in $X$, and $A$ is a deformation retract of an open set $U$ of $X_2$. Show that $X_1$ is a deformation retract of $U \bigcup X$; conclude that $(X_1,X_2)$ is an excisive couple.

Well, to get started, I just laid out some definitions. Eventually I will want to show that $(X_1,X_2)$ is an excisive couple, which means that the inclusion:

$S(X_1) + S(X_2) -> S(X)$ induces an isomorphism in homology.

If $A$ is a deformation retract of an open set $U$ of $X_2$ and $A=X_1 \bigcap X_2$, then, well, something fishy is going on....

Comment: Are you using Hatcher's text?

Comment: No I am not. I am using Munkre's Elements of Algebraic Topology. This is exercise #5 on the section of Mayer-Vietoris sequences of Singular Homology