# excisive couples, sufficient conditions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Question: What are sufficient conditions on pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ so that $(A\times Y,X\times B)$ is an excisive couple?

In more detail: Given pairs of spaces $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$, consider the inclusion
$$
\Delta(A\times Y) + \Delta(X \times B) \to \Delta(A\times Y \cup X\times B)
$$
Here $\Delta(A\times Y) + \Delta(X \times B)$ denotes the subcomplex of the singular chain complex $\Delta(A\times Y \cup X\times B)$ generated by those singular simplices whose image is completely contained in one of $A\times Y$ or $X\times B$.

**Question:** Under which circumstances is this map a weak equivalence (i.e. induces isomorphisms in homology)?

It is clear to me that $A=B$, one of $A,B$ is empty and $A,B$ are both open are sufficient. I am learning from lecture notes which claim that it also follows "feom excision results" in case the inclusions are closed cofibrations, but I have no idea how to prove this. I'd love to get a reference. Also what happens when $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ are NDR pairs?

Comment: I don't think $(A \times Y, X \times B)$ is what you want to consider (for one, it is not generally a couple on the nose), do you perhaps mean $(X \times Y, A \times Y \cup X \times B)$?

Comment: @BenSteffan I am working with the definition of an excisive couple from Spanier, Algebraic Topology, page 188. It is the same definition as the one used in this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681767/showing-a-pair-is-an-excisive-couple-mayer-vietoris-sequence-singular-homology

Comment: @BenSteffan I believe the chain map above is the one that needs to be a weak equivalence if one wants to define relative products, so I believe it is what I want to consider! :)

Comment: Ah I see, that's not notation I was familiar with :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some observations (no claims of exhaustiveness):

- The map is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ is a union of path-components of $X$ or $B$ is a union of path-components of $Y$. (E.g. if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$.)
- The map is a chain-homotopy equivalence if and only if it is a quasi-isomorphism (you call it weak equivalence) since both complexes are free.
- The excision theorem tells us that a sufficient condition is that $X\times B\cup A\times Y$ is the union of the interiors of $X\times B$ and $A\times Y$ respectively in $X\times B\cup A\times Y$. This is the case if $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ are open (I don't see any other practical sufficient condition).
- The map is a quasi-isomorphism if the inclusions $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ are closed and one of them is a cofibration. Firstly, this implies that $X\times B$ and $A\times Y$ are closed in $X\times Y$, hence closed in $X\times B\cup A\times Y$. Thus, we have a pushout diagram
  $$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  A\times B @>>> X\times B\\
  @VVV @VVV\\
  A\times Y @>>> X\times B\cup A\times Y
  \end{CD}.
  $$
  Now, closed cofibrations are compatible with products so the claim is implied by the following

  **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a top. space and $A,B\subseteq X$ closed subspaces s.t. $X=A\cup B$. If $(A,A\cap B)$ is cofibered, the inclusion $\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)\le\Delta(X)$ is a quasi-isomorphism, i.e. $(X;A,B)$ is excisive.

  *Proof:* The closedness implies that $X$ is the pushout of $A$ and $B$ along $A\cap B$. Let $Z$ be the corresponding homotopy pushout, i.e. $Z=A\cup_{A\cap B}(A\cap B)\times I\cup_{A\cap B}B$, and $p\colon Z\rightarrow X$ the natural projection map. Now, $Z$ is the union of the open subsets $U=Z\setminus B$ and $V=Z\setminus A$ and $p$ restricts to homotopy equivalences $p_A\colon U\rightarrow A$, $p_B\colon V\rightarrow B$ and $p_{A\cap B}\colon U\cap V\rightarrow A\cap B$. Furthermore, the condition that $(A,A\cap B)$ is cofibered implies that $p$ is a homotopy equivalence. Consider the diagram of short exact sequences
  $$
  \begin{CD}
  0 @>>> \Delta(U\cap V) @>>> \Delta(U)\oplus\Delta(V) @>>> \Delta(U)+\Delta(V) @>>> 0\\
  @. @VV{p_{A\cap B,\ast}}V @VV{p_{A,\ast}\oplus p_{B,\ast}}V @VV{p_{A,\ast}+p_{B,\ast}}V @.\\
  0 @>>> \Delta(A\cap B) @>>> \Delta(A)\oplus\Delta(B) @>>> \Delta(A)+\Delta(B) @>>> 0
  \end{CD}.
  $$
  The natural long exact sequence in homology implies, since $p_{A,\ast}$, $p_{B,\ast}$ and $p_{A\cap B,\ast}$ are quasi-isomorphisms, that $p_{A,\ast}+p_{B,\ast}\colon\Delta(U)+\Delta(V)\rightarrow\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)$ is a quasi-isomorphism. Now, consider the diagram
  $$
  \begin{CD}
  \Delta(U)+\Delta(V) @>>> \Delta(Z)\\
  @VV{p_{A,\ast}+p_{B,\ast}}V @V{p_{\ast}}VV\\
  \Delta(A)+\Delta(B) @>>> \Delta(X)
  \end{CD}.
  $$
  The left vertical map is a quasi-isomorphism as demonstrated. The right vertical map is a quasi-isomorphism since $p$ is a homotopy-equivalence. The top horizontal map is a quasi-isomorphism by the excision theorem. Thus, the bottom horizontal map is a quasi-isomorphism.$\blacksquare$
- The map is a quasi-isomorphism if $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ are closed and one of the pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is good. In the same way as the previous bullet point, this reduces to the lemma (which is precisely the problem statement of the linked question)

  **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a top. space and $A,B\subseteq X$ closed subspaces s.t. $X=A\cup B$. If $(B,A\cap B)$ is a good pair, the inclusion $\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)\le\Delta(X)$ is a quasi-isomorphism, i.e. $(X;A,B)$ is excisive.

  *Proof:* The assumption implies that there is an open $V\supseteq A\cap B$ in $B$ s.t. $V$ deformation retracts to $A\cap B$. There is an open $U$ in $X$ s.t. $V=B\cap U$. Note that $A\cup V=A\cup U$ and $B\setminus A\cap B$ are open in $X$. The excision theorem thus implies that $\Delta(A\cup V)+\Delta(B)\rightarrow\Delta(X)$ is a quasi-isomorphism. A deformation retraction of $V$ to $A\cap B$ induces a deformation retraction of $A\cup V$ to $A$ that is constant on $A$. This implies (comparing long exact sequences as in the previous lemma) that $\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)\rightarrow\Delta(A\cup V)+\Delta(B)$ is a quasi-isomorphism. Thus, the composite $\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)\rightarrow\Delta(X)$ is a quasi-isomorphism.$\blacksquare$